# Erro em chaves primárias e secundárias

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Bom, tentei normalizar o máximo essa tabela de dados, contudo obtive um fracasso na hora de pegar o código, onde não estou identificando o erro no usuário:

Tabela:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro 2:

```
 -- Geração de Modelo físico
-- Sql ANSI 2003 - brModelo.



CREATE TABLE Data_Evento (
id_data_evento INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
data_inicio DATE,
data_fim DATE
);

CREATE TABLE Hora_Evento (
id_hora INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_evento INTEGER,
hora_inicio TIME,
hora_fim TIME
);

CREATE TABLE Usuario (
id_usuario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(),
RG VARCHAR(),
usuario VARCHAR(255),
senha VARCHAR(255),
imagem LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Controle (
id_controle INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(),
RG VARCHAR(),
data_cadastro DATETIME,
data_entrada DATETIME,
data_saida DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE aluno_curso (
id_aluno_curso INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(),
RG VARCHAR(),
id_curso INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Noticia (
id_noticia INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
titulo VARCHAR(255),
autor VARCHAR(255),
descricao LONGTEXT,
data DATE,
fonte LONGTEXT,
imagem LONGTEXT,
imagem_2 LONGTEXT,
imagem_3 LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Telefone_Professor (
id_telefone_professor INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_professor INTEGER,
telefone VARCHAR(9),
celular VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Evento (
id_evento INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_data_evento INTEGER,
id_hora INTEGER,
titulo VARCHAR(255),
descricao LONGTEXT,
preco VARCHAR(10),
imagem LONGTEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(id_data_evento) REFERENCES Data_Evento (id_data_evento),
FOREIGN KEY(id_hora) REFERENCES Hora_Evento (id_hora)
);

CREATE TABLE Professor (
id_professor INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_especialidade INTEGER,
id_telefone_professor INTEGER,
id_aula INTEGER,
nome VARCHAR(255),
sobrenome VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255),
Imagem LONGTEXT,
descricao LONGTEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(id_telefone_professor) REFERENCES Telefone_Professor (id_telefone_professor)
);

CREATE TABLE Aula (
id_aula INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
tipo VARCHAR(255),
data DATE,
duracao TIME
);

CREATE TABLE Promocao (
id_promocao INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_curso INTEGER,
titulo VARCHAR(255),
promocao VARCHAR(255),
validade DATE,
descricao LONGTEXT,
imagem LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Curso (
id_curso INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
titulo VARCHAR(255),
descricao LONGTEXT,
carga VARCHAR(255),
imagem LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Aluno_Evento (
id_aluno_evento INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
id_evento INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(),
RG VARCHAR(),
FOREIGN KEY(id_evento) REFERENCES Evento (id_evento)
);

CREATE TABLE Endereco (
id_endereco INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(),
RG VARCHAR(),
rua LONGTEXT,
numero VARCHAR(10),
cep VARCHAR(14),
pais VARCHAR(255),
estado VARCHAR(2),
cidade VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Aluno (
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(14),
RG VARCHAR(12),
id_usuario INTEGER,
id_controle INTEGER,
id_aluno_promocao INTEGER,
nome VARCHAR(255),
sobrenome VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255),
nacionalidade VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(id_aluno,CPF,RG),
FOREIGN KEY(id_usuario) REFERENCES Usuario (id_usuario),
FOREIGN KEY(id_controle) REFERENCES Controle (id_controle)
);

CREATE TABLE Telefone (
id_telefone INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(),
RG VARCHAR(),
telefone VARCHAR(9),
celular VARCHAR(10),
FOREIGN KEY(RG,,,) REFERENCES Aluno (id_aluno,CPF,RG)
);

CREATE TABLE Modulo (
id_modulo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_curso INTEGER,
id_professor INTEGER,
titulo VARCHAR(255),
descricao LONGTEXT,
conteudo LONGTEXT,
imagem LONGTEXT,
imagem_2 LONGTEXT,
preco VARCHAR(100),
FOREIGN KEY(id_curso) REFERENCES Curso (id_curso),
FOREIGN KEY(id_professor) REFERENCES Professor (id_professor)
);

CREATE TABLE Especialidade (
id_especialidade INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
especialidade LONGTEXT,
formacao LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Aluno_Promocao (
id_aluno_promocao INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(),
RG VARCHAR(),
id_promocao INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(RG,,,) REFERENCES Aluno (id_aluno,CPF,RG),
FOREIGN KEY(id_promocao) REFERENCES Promocao (id_promocao)
);

ALTER TABLE Hora_Evento ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_evento) REFERENCES Evento (id_evento)
ALTER TABLE Usuario ADD FOREIGN KEY(/*erro: ??*/) REFERENCES Aluno (id_aluno,CPF,RG)
ALTER TABLE aluno_curso ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_curso) REFERENCES Curso (id_curso)
ALTER TABLE Telefone_Professor ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_professor) REFERENCES Professor (id_professor)
ALTER TABLE Professor ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_especialidade) REFERENCES Especialidade (id_especialidade)
ALTER TABLE Professor ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_aula) REFERENCES Aula (id_aula)
ALTER TABLE Promocao ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_curso) REFERENCES Curso (id_curso)
ALTER TABLE Aluno ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_aluno_promocao) REFERENCES Aluno_Promocao (id_aluno_promocao)
```

Está indicando um erro em usuário

Comment: Poderia postar a mensagem de erro para melhor identificação?

Comment: Claro, bruno101.

Comment: Desculpe, só um minuto que altero já. Como posso colocar a foto danieltakeshi sem ter que colocar o código da imagem?

Comment: para postar o código como texto basta copiar e colar aqui o código SQL selecionar todo ele e clicar na opção Código. ou dar 4 espaços em cada linha que for codigo.

Comment: Ok, obrigado Will.

Comment: Eu editei agora, está certo... Correto? Ou eu não entendi muito bem a afirmação do danieltakeshi. Era apenas editar uma imagem ou todas?

Comment: isso ai, creio que apenas a imagem que continha o código as outras não tem como escrever.

Comment: ps: tenta definir os  varchar() que está vazio para varchar(20)

Comment: Para evitar uma discussão longa sobre a resolução do problema, melhor abrirmos o chat, por favor me chame por lá, não sei como funciona. PS: O varchar não tem como mudar, pois é da chave estrangeira e já vem assim vazio (está puxando do aluno)

Answer (score 0):

A chave estrangeira precisa ter os campos referenciados que são chave primária na tabela referenciada.

Neste caso você está referenciando a chave da tabela **Aluno** e essa chave é composta por 3 campos: **id_aluno**, **CPF** e **RG**. Assim todas tabelas que referenciam a tabela **Aluno** devem conter os 3 campos **id_aluno**, **CPF** e **RG**.

Na tabela **Aluno_Promocao**, por exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
FOREIGN KEY(id_aluno,CPF,RG) REFERENCES Aluno (id_aluno,CPF,RG)
```

Comment: Isso inclui as tabelas N:N?

Comment: acho q uma possível solução para não ser necessária a replicação dos 3 campos para as tabelas, sejam transformar *CPF* e *RG* em índices únicos e *id_aluno* ser a única chave primária.

Comment: Ocorreu novamente o mesmo erro em usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Erros encontrados:

- Tabela Aluno Com mais de 1 Primary key, você pode ter apenas 1
  Primary key por tabela.
- Declaração de Foreign key faltando parametros

ps: também foi declarado o tamanho do Varchar para CPF's e RG's que estavam sem, se você quiser pode alterar o valor contanto que não os deixe em branco.

Testa o SQL Agora para ver qualquer duvida Estou a disposição.

```
-- Geração de Modelo físico
-- Sql ANSI 2003 - brModelo.



CREATE TABLE Data_Evento (
id_data_evento INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
data_inicio DATE,
data_fim DATE
);

CREATE TABLE Hora_Evento (
id_hora INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_evento INTEGER,
hora_inicio TIME,
hora_fim TIME
);

CREATE TABLE Usuario (
id_usuario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(20),
RG VARCHAR(20),
usuario VARCHAR(255),
senha VARCHAR(255),
imagem LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Controle (
id_controle INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(20),
RG VARCHAR(20),
data_cadastro DATETIME,
data_entrada DATETIME,
data_saida DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE aluno_curso (
id_aluno_curso INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(20),
RG VARCHAR(20),
id_curso INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Noticia (
id_noticia INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
titulo VARCHAR(255),
autor VARCHAR(255),
descricao LONGTEXT,
data DATE,
fonte LONGTEXT,
imagem LONGTEXT,
imagem_2 LONGTEXT,
imagem_3 LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Telefone_Professor (
id_telefone_professor INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_professor INTEGER,
telefone VARCHAR(9),
celular VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Evento (
id_evento INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_data_evento INTEGER,
id_hora INTEGER,
titulo VARCHAR(255),
descricao LONGTEXT,
preco VARCHAR(10),
imagem LONGTEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(id_data_evento) REFERENCES Data_Evento (id_data_evento),
FOREIGN KEY(id_hora) REFERENCES Hora_Evento (id_hora)
);

CREATE TABLE Professor (
id_professor INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_especialidade INTEGER,
id_telefone_professor INTEGER,
id_aula INTEGER,
nome VARCHAR(255),
sobrenome VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255),
Imagem LONGTEXT,
descricao LONGTEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(id_telefone_professor) REFERENCES Telefone_Professor (id_telefone_professor)
);

CREATE TABLE Aula (
id_aula INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
tipo VARCHAR(255),
data DATE,
duracao TIME
);

CREATE TABLE Promocao (
id_promocao INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_curso INTEGER,
titulo VARCHAR(255),
promocao VARCHAR(255),
validade DATE,
descricao LONGTEXT,
imagem LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Curso (
id_curso INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
titulo VARCHAR(255),
descricao LONGTEXT,
carga VARCHAR(255),
imagem LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Aluno_Evento (
id_aluno_evento INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
id_evento INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(20),
RG VARCHAR(20),
FOREIGN KEY(id_evento) REFERENCES Evento (id_evento)
);

CREATE TABLE Endereco (
id_endereco INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(20),
RG VARCHAR(20),
rua LONGTEXT,
numero VARCHAR(10),
cep VARCHAR(14),
pais VARCHAR(255),
estado VARCHAR(2),
cidade VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Aluno (
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(14),
RG VARCHAR(12),
id_usuario INTEGER,
id_controle INTEGER,
id_aluno_promocao INTEGER,
nome VARCHAR(255),
sobrenome VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255),
nacionalidade VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(id_aluno),
FOREIGN KEY(id_usuario) REFERENCES Usuario (id_usuario),
FOREIGN KEY(id_controle) REFERENCES Controle (id_controle)
);

CREATE TABLE Telefone (
id_telefone INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(20),
RG VARCHAR(20),
telefone VARCHAR(9),
celular VARCHAR(10),
FOREIGN KEY(id_aluno,CPF,RG) REFERENCES Aluno (id_aluno,CPF,RG)
);

CREATE TABLE Modulo (
id_modulo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_curso INTEGER,
id_professor INTEGER,
titulo VARCHAR(255),
descricao LONGTEXT,
conteudo LONGTEXT,
imagem LONGTEXT,
imagem_2 LONGTEXT,
preco VARCHAR(100),
FOREIGN KEY(id_curso) REFERENCES Curso (id_curso),
FOREIGN KEY(id_professor) REFERENCES Professor (id_professor)
);

CREATE TABLE Especialidade (
id_especialidade INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
especialidade LONGTEXT,
formacao LONGTEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Aluno_Promocao (
id_aluno_promocao INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
id_aluno INTEGER,
CPF VARCHAR(20),
RG VARCHAR(20),
id_promocao INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(id_aluno,CPF,RG) REFERENCES Aluno (id_aluno,CPF,RG),
FOREIGN KEY(id_promocao) REFERENCES Promocao (id_promocao)
);

ALTER TABLE Hora_Evento ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_evento) REFERENCES Evento (id_evento)
ALTER TABLE Usuario ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_aluno,CPF,RG) REFERENCES Aluno (id_aluno,CPF,RG)
ALTER TABLE aluno_curso ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_curso) REFERENCES Curso (id_curso)
ALTER TABLE Telefone_Professor ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_professor) REFERENCES Professor (id_professor)
ALTER TABLE Professor ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_especialidade) REFERENCES Especialidade (id_especialidade)
ALTER TABLE Professor ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_aula) REFERENCES Aula (id_aula)
ALTER TABLE Promocao ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_curso) REFERENCES Curso (id_curso)
ALTER TABLE Aluno ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_aluno_promocao) REFERENCES Aluno_Promocao (id_aluno_promocao)
```

Algumas dicas:

- Nunca declare variáveis com a primeira letra maiúscula, até onde sei não muda praticamente nada, porem para manutenção e organização do código fica melhor.

  **Ex:** [Errado] CPF VARCHAR(255)  [Correto] cpf VARCHAR(255)

Comment: Bom, não é querendo uma resposta mais técnica assim, mas como aplico uma chave composta em uma tabela? Pq o que eu realmente queria era aplicar a chave composta igual este exemplo. http://www.vbweb.com.br/forum_resp.asp?Forum=VB&Codigo=221035                possui uma outra sintaxe ou algo do tipo??! Então, sobre os CPF e RG estão em brancos ele não deixa eu alterar na tabela, ele liga diretamente já o relacionamento sem eu puder mexer. Agora o CPF e o RG maisculos vou trocar igual você disse. Muito obrigado Will, se puder me esclarecer mais agradeço.

Comment: Olha de maneira rápida, respondo melhor quando chegar em casa, seria vc utilizar no no cpf e rg assim: cpf VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE, com o atributo UNIQUE vc diz que esse valor deve ser único seria tipo uma primary key, ou seja, não poderá ter outra com o mesmo valor na mesma tabela.

Comment: Entendi, valeu.